# research papers on mean average precision

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow, object-detection

I've been coding YOLOv1 from scratch, are there any good papers which explain and/or give code (or pseudocode) for mean average precision? I searched but couldn't find good ones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is paper which answer your question [Beinan Wang - A PARALLEL IMPLEMENTATION OF COMPUTING
MEAN AVERAGE PRECISION](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2206.09504v1.pdf)
it has the implementation in pseudocode.

Comment: From review - Thanks for your answer. I've edited the answer to include the name of the author of the paper you link to. It's good practice to do this to ensure the original author gets credit for their work. See https://datascience.stackexchange.com/help/referencing.